# Table would not fit in the page

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Modelling steps}
\vspace{1mm}
\label{tab:steps}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{34CDF9} 
\textbf{Step}           & \textbf{Description}                                                   & \textbf{Addressed in} \\ \hline
Problem formulation     & Identifying the problem  or research question to be investigated       &                       \\
System Decomposition    & Deciding system composition, its internal structure and the boundaries &                       \\
Concept Formlisation    & Generalising system description to make it interpretable by a computer &                       \\
Model Formalisation     & Agent narrative                                                        &                       \\
Software Implementation & Implementing the model in a programming language                       &                       \\
Model verification      & Translation of conceptual model to computational model                 &                       \\
Experimentation         & Performing the planned experiments or scenarios                        &                       \\
Data analysis           & Exploring, Interpreting and Visualising the data obtained from model   &                       \\
Model validation        & Accurate representation of real-world system                           &                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Add  `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%` before the line `\begin{tabular}{lll}` and `}` after  
`\end{tabular}`

Comment: \begin{table}[h]
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
.....\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L{1}L{1}L{1}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}